# Why is there not enough system RAM for simple huggingface models?

Tags: google-colaboratory, ram, huggingface

I would love to run this model (https://huggingface.co/openaccess-ai-collective/manticore-13b) and even bought Colab Plus but it can not run it despite 25GB system RAM. Would this be running on a good laptop? How much system RAM is needed? Is it possible to see somewhere what system requirements are needed? Can I change the code somehow so that it is running?

I want to run a HuggingFace modell but it is crashing always.